# Why am I getting this file error and a cat error even though I am passing the text file in the argument?

Tags: bash, shell, cat

The program calls for us to read in the directory full of text files, parse data from those files into their respective attributes.

Then once the data is set, load a general template which has those attributes in the text.
I'm using a sed command to replace the specific attributes, only if the number of students is greater than 50. If so it runs the sed command and writes to a file, and into a directory.

But i am getting this error when I'm passing

```
test3.sh ./data assign4.template 12/16/2021 ./output
```

Error

```
cat: assign4.template: No such file or directory
test3.sh: line 62: output/MAT3103.crs: No such file or directory
The current file is MAT4353.crs
```

Now what I am thinking is that, for the file or directory error, it is looking in that folder and searching for a file named that

But Not entirely sure how to resolve that.

As for the cat: template error, I don't get that since I am passing the template in the terminal

As for the other paramaters being passed, the Date which is also substituted in the sed command, All output files should be written to the directory defined by the last argument. This directory may or may not already exist. Each file should be named by the course’s department code and number,and with the extension.warn

Here is the total code

```
#!/bin/bash

# checking if user has passed atleast four arguments are passed
if [ $# -ne 4 ]
then
    echo "Atleast 4 argument should be passed"
    exit 1
fi

# if output directory exits check
if [ -d output ] 
then
    # if output directory exists will get deleted
    echo "output directory already exists. So removing its contents"
    rm -f output/*
else
    # output directory does not exist, so gets created here
    echo "output directory does not exist. So creating a new directory"
    mkdir output
fi

max_students=50
template=$2
dt=$3

cd $1
    for i in *; do
    echo The current file is ${i}

    dept_code=$(awk 'NR==2
    {print $1 ; exit}' $i)
    echo $dept_code

    dept_name=$(awk 'NR==2
    {print $2 ; exit}' $i)
    echo $dept_name

    course_name=$(awk 'FNR==2' $i)
    echo $course_name

    course_sched=$(awk 'FNR==3' $i | awk '{print $1}')

    course_sched=$(awk 'FNR==3' $i | awk '{print $1}')
    echo $course_sched

    course_start=$(awk 'FNR==3' $i | awk '{print $2}')
    echo $course_start

    course_end=$(awk 'FNR==3' $i | awk '{print $3}')
    echo $course_end

    credit_hours=$(awk 'FNR==4' $i)
    echo $credit_hours

    num_students=$(awk 'FNR==5' $i)
    echo $num_students

    # checking if number of students currently enrolled > max students
    if (( $(echo "$num_students > $max_students" |bc -l) ))
    then
# output filename creation
    out_file=${i}
# using example Template and sed command to replace the variables
    cat $template | sed -e "s/\[\\[\dept_code\]\]/$dept_code/" | sed -e "s/\[\\[\dept_name\]\]/$dept_name/" | sed -e "s|\[\[course_name\]\]|$course_name|" | sed -e "s|\[\[course_start\]\]|$$

fi

done
```

Comment: Always check your `bash` scripts with [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fix your errors in the script.

Comment: I believe error is self explanatory `No such file or directory` so you could do 2 things, either give file name with absolute path OR `cd` to that file's path in your code before fetching it or doing some operation to it? Let us know how it goes then.

Comment: The `cd $1` command  moves down into the "data" folder, since that's what was passed as `$1`. After that, all file names and relative paths are *relative to that directory*. That is, it's looking for data/assign4.template and data/output/MAT3103.crs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson 

so essentially, It is looking for the template file IN data, that why it's giving the error

what would the way to fix that be with still iterating through the directory?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 

i don't think I can give it a absolute path, since that would be against the rules of the assignment, its supposed to be a "general" type of code

so i don't know if i can even cd into the file either right?

Comment: @RoleChapa Use `for i in "$1"/*; do`. Also, I second user3439894's recommendation of [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) -- there are a number of common bad practices in your script (mostly unquoted variable references) that it'll point out.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you, that did get rid of the cat error i was getting

I am still getting the other error of "the file is not found" i think someone else commented something about that, let me try and see if not i'll reply back to you for more help

and yes, after i sort this out, i'll run the code thru the checker

Comment: THANK YOU TO EVERYONE GOT IT WORKING !!!

Answer (score 1):

You define the variable as

```
template=$2
```

and since your second parameter is `assign4.template`, this is what the variable `template` is set to. Then you do a

```
cat $template
```

which is, first of all, unnecessary, since you can do an input redirection on `sed` instead, but most of all requires, that the file exists in your working directory. Since you have done before a

```
cd $1
```

it means that the file `data/assign4.template` does not exist. You have to create this file before you can use your script.

Answer (score -1):

use single quotes in your positional arguments.

`test3.sh './data' 'assign4.template' '12/16/2021' './output'`

or

`test3.sh data assign4.template '12/16/2021' output`

Comment: Nope, still getting the same errors. Any other idea?

Comment: @AkhilJalagam : There are no spaces or other special characters in the arguments. How could quoting possibly help in this case?